Camera not working in Ubuntu 24.04 for my Dell XPS 13 9320
After installing Ubuntu 24.04 I realised that the Camera is not working. Please guide


I think is related to this dell article
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000225004/precision-5480-mobile-workstation-webcam-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-24-04

Ubuntu and Canonical advise that the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS operating system is adding support for the MIPI webcam. However, due to an issue found during testing the release has been delayed until July 1, 2024.

There is multiple issues with intel MIPI cameras

Any update on this?

I don't have a Dell to validate, but didn't look like the issue is fixed. Do a google search about the new Kernel 6.10 seams took have new compatibility updates there with the IPU6 cameras driver being upstream in this version. Maybe still have to wait a little longer for this version.

Confirmed on my Dell 9320, Ubuntu 24.04.1, now that it has been officially point-released.

related discussion: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=297262&p=2

@HenriqueLaPorta so far Ubuntu is at 6.8 so yes will have to wait and still it is not clear

@M.AhmadZafar Didn't get your question? Ubuntu 24.10 is already on kernel 6.11 if you want to test. For my case in a Acer still not working.
I don't follow up the issue closer anymore, but u can see more information about what is been done in the Github page: https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers/issues or in the bug page for Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ipu6-drivers

I had the same issue. I installed cheese and it helped
First, check if you already have cheese: Run cheese in the terminal. It will prompt cheese if it's installed
If you need to install it, enter sudo apt-get install cheese in the terminal

No cheese can't help.
